# PHP: bad request on file_get_contents URL

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents, urlencode

here's my code:

```
$url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed_–_Rocky’s_Legacy";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

The problem is the special characters in the URL - it works if i use the encoded URL (which i can copy/paste from the Browser)

```
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed_%E2%80%93_Rocky%E2%80%99s_Legacy
```

I tried using `urlencode()` but it will encode the whole string and won't work at all:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCreed_%96_Rocky%92s_Legacy
```

So, how can i encode special characters on URLs like that?

Comment: Your code works here. Are you running from cli or http server? Which php version? Also, what is the encoding of your file and default php encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode only the last part of the url

```
$url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/" . urlencode("Creed_–_Rocky’s_Legacy");
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Or, if your $url variable changes:

```
$url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed_–_Rocky’s_Legacy";
$html = file_get_contents(dirname($url) . "/" . urlencode(basename($url)));
```